# xtext importURI references cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, scoping

I'm developing a DSL which reuses types that are defined in another DSL. Basically I have two file extensions let's say .A and .B, some entities are declared in the .A and I need to access them in .B. I'm using importURI to only have access to the references I need from .A.

The code completion works perfectly, it gives me the entities that are declared in the .A, but the problem is that I see error messages saying that the references cannot be resolved.

I've done the same thing as suggested in this post [xtext importURI external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034734/xtext-importuri-external-file) and here are my workflow fragments:

```
         // Java API to access grammar elements (required by several other fragments)
            fragment = grammarAccess.GrammarAccessFragment auto-inject {}

            // generates Java API for the generated EPackages
            fragment = ecore.EMFGeneratorFragment auto-inject {}

            // the old serialization component
            // fragment = parseTreeConstructor.ParseTreeConstructorFragment auto-inject {}    

            // serializer 2.0
            fragment = serializer.SerializerFragment auto-inject {
                generateStub = false
            }

            // a custom ResourceFactory for use with EMF
            fragment = resourceFactory.ResourceFactoryFragment auto-inject {}

            // The antlr parser generator fragment.
            fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment auto-inject {
            //  options = {
            //      backtrack = true
            //  }
            }

            // Xtend-based API for validation
            fragment = validation.ValidatorFragment auto-inject {
                composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.ImportUriValidator"
                composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
            }

            // old scoping and exporting API
            fragment = scoping.ImportURIScopingFragment auto-inject {}
            // fragment = exporting.SimpleNamesFragment auto-inject {}

            // scoping and exporting API
            fragment = scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment auto-inject {}
            fragment = exporting.QualifiedNamesFragment auto-inject {}
            //fragment = builder.BuilderIntegrationFragment auto-inject {}

            // generator API
            //fragment = generator.GeneratorFragment auto-inject {}

            // formatter API
            //fragment = formatting.FormatterFragment auto-inject {}

            // labeling API
            //fragment = labeling.LabelProviderFragment auto-inject {}

            // outline API
            //fragment = outline.OutlineTreeProviderFragment auto-inject {}
            //fragment = outline.QuickOutlineFragment auto-inject {}

            // quickfix API
            fragment = quickfix.QuickfixProviderFragment auto-inject {}

            // content assist API
            fragment = contentAssist.ContentAssistFragment auto-inject {}

            // generates a more lightweight Antlr parser and lexer tailored for content assist
            fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment auto-inject {}

            // generates junit test support classes into Generator#pathTestProject
            //fragment = junit.Junit4Fragment auto-inject {}

            // rename refactoring
            //fragment = refactoring.RefactorElementNameFragment auto-inject {}

            // provides the necessary bindings for java types integration
            //fragment = types.TypesGeneratorFragment auto-inject {}

            // generates the required bindings only if the grammar inherits from Xbase
            //fragment = xbase.XbaseGeneratorFragment auto-inject {}

            // provides a preference page for template proposals
            //fragment = templates.CodetemplatesGeneratorFragment auto-inject {}

            // provides a compare view
            //fragment = compare.CompareFragment auto-inject {}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share grammar and sample models as well?
and you should remove

    fragment = scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment auto-inject {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Christian, got it working by regenerating a default .mwe2 and commenting those two fragments

```
    //generates the required bindings only if the grammar inherits from Xbase
    //fragment = xbase.XbaseGeneratorFragment auto-inject {}

    //provides a preference page for template proposals
    //fragment = templates.CodetemplatesGeneratorFragment auto-inject {}
```